# Map between curves and integral points

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Suppose we have an equation of two variables $x,y$, for example $E: x^3+y^3=d$, and we have a bijective map
\begin{align*}
\varphi: E &\to F\\
(x,y) &\mapsto \left(\frac{3d}{x+y},-\frac{9dy}{x+y}\right)
\end{align*}
where $F$ is the (nonsingular) elliptic curve $F : y^2=x^3-432d^2$. If 
we prove that $F$ doesn't have integer solutions (or has finitely many) is that sufficient to prove that $E$ doesn't have solutions (or has finitely many solutions)? In other words, does the bijective map  $\varphi$ from equation to elliptic curve preserve the structure between them?i don't mean this example i mean in general specialy 
Integer map .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: In general, a map defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ (as in your example) will preserve rational points, but need not preserve integral points. However, if you can determine the set of primes $S$ occurring in the possible denominators introduced by $\varphi$, you can still solve your problem by computing all $S$-integral points. You may find the reference in this answer helpful: https://mathoverflow.net/a/15986/